# Manually start Kerio VPN

Tags: 13.04, vpn

I've installed Kerio VPN client for my Ubuntu (13.04 x64). It starts automatically on system startup. ([Manual](http://download.kerio.com/dwn/kwf/kerio-kvc.README))

I want to be able to control it manually.

**UPDATE**
I don't want it to start automatically. Actually I wan't to disable its automatic startup and then start it whenever I want. I've used some configuration tools to disable automatic startup but it never get started manually.

Answer (score 13):

You can simply remove any system startup links:

```
sudo update-rc.d -f kerio-kvc remove
```

Read more here: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/update-rc.d.8.html

Comment: Then you control the service manually:

sudo service kerio-kvc start|stop|restart|reload

Answer (score 2):

Kerio VPN Client will be automatically started after installation 
and restarted after reconfiguration. 
You can start/stop it manually by invoking the command:

# /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc {start|stop|restart}

Comment: I think I should have explained more about my problem which is added now on the question.